# How can I prevent ed printing match results?

Tags: bash, ed

I use `ed` in a bash script to search a file; the `/` command will display the content, which I don't want. I tried to redirect `>/dev/null 2>&1` but that didn't work for me.

#### text file `foo.txt`:

```
a
b
c
```

#### bash script `bar.sh`:

```
ed -s foo.txt << EOF
/b/
EOF
> /dev/null 2>&1
```

#### result:

```
$ ./bar.sh
b
```

How can I stop `ed` printing the matched line `b`?

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to do? I mean, you can find a `b` using `grep`?

Comment: @lutz horn ,  search command of ed  will print out  what it found, i don't want it to print , i only need the address to do other things.

Comment: That was my question - what other things? There is probably a better tool.

Comment: yes , grep is better for search.  in fact, i not only need search , but also edit the file , e.g. firstly locate the some specified string in file , then delete few lines after that,  add some lines new ,finally save these changes back to the file. i know ed can do the job. do u have better suggestion, i appreciate

Comment: `awk` or `sed` will do that very easily. Questions are free. I suggest you ask another question, tag it with `awk` and `sed`, and say 1) what you want to find, b) how many lines you want to delete afterwards, and c) what you want to add. I am sure you will get good answers within 10 minutes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
ed -s foo.txt > /dev/null <<eof
/b/
eof
```

Comment: Great, it works!  I want to know if these is a way prevent printing  in ed

Comment: @redmark You can use `-s` which will suppress diagnostics, but that's about it AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ed` commenting command  **`/b/;#`** to move to a matched line without printing the result.

According to `ed` documentation

> `'(.,.)#'`
>
> Begins a comment; the rest of the line, up to a newline, is
>        ignored. **If a line address followed by a semicolon is given, then
>        the current address is set to that address**. Otherwise, the current
>        address is unchanged.